# How to join every X amount of characters together in an Array - Ruby

Tags: ruby

If I want to join every X amount of letters together in an array how could I implement this? 
In this case I want to join every two letters together

```
 Input: array = ["b", "i", "e", "t", "r", "o"]   
 Output: array = ["bi", "et", "ro"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`each_slice` (docs)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
arr = 'bietro'.split ''

# grab each slice of 2 elements
p arr.each_slice(2).to_a
  #=> [["b", "i"], ["e", "t"], ["r", "o"]]

# map `join' over each of the slices
p arr.each_slice(2).map(&:join)
  #=> ["bi", "et", "ro"]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Doorknow shows the best way, but here are two (among many, many) other ways:

```
def bunch_em(arr,n)
  ((arr.size+n-1)/n).times.map { |i| arr.slice(i*n,n).join }
end

arr = ["b", "i", "e", "t", "r", "o"] 
bunch_em(arr,2) #=> ["bi", "et", "ro"]
```